# Install my app from a Website like GBA4iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate

I recently downloaded GBA4iOS and NDS4iOS! I though they were really cool, and I noticed that they didn't need to be installed from the App Store.

I am a registered Apple iOS Developer, so I can create certificates. I was wondering how I would allow my App to be downloaded from my website. Please help! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a different account than the regular developer account. Eg. one for enterprise distribution. However, although technically possible doing so would certainly put your account and its certificates on risk.

Google for iOS OTA installations (Over The Air) for more details.

We do this a lot, but within the organizational limits of our company of course.